# Icons not showing in Spring project with Bootstrap

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I am utilising the Bootstrap front end framework, although I am having some trouble getting the icons to load. I have implemented Spring security, I am not sure whether this may be affecting them not to load. I am calling my .css and .js files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/style/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

This is the configuration that I have in my Dispatcher servlet config:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**" />
```

This is really irritating, can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: Do your Javascript and CSS files load properly? What status is presented by the browser? For example a 403 status could indicate spring security is denying access to the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your spring security config, have you excluded your resources directory containing your css, js, images from the secured zone ?

```
<http use-expressions="true" security="none"  pattern="/resources/**">
</http>
```

If the problem is only related to the twitter bootstrap icons, have you included the files glyphicons-halflings.png glyphicons-halflingswhite.png in a resources/img folder ?